# Setting UIImage to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view that loads images from backend server but my problem is setting the images to each of the collectionViewCells. The pictures are being retrieved as I saw from `NSLog`. I created a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` called CollectionCell and created a property for a `UIImageView *parseImageView`. Now the collection view displays the correct number of cells but the images do not appear in them. Collection view is made without storyboard. `imageFilesArray` is what contains the retrieved image data(image files).

From my ViewController containing collectionView

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self.ImageCollView registerClass:[CollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    CollectionCell *cell = (CollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *imageObject = [imageFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            cell.parseImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        }

    }];

    return cell;

}
```

CollectionCell.h

```
@interface CollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImageView *parseImageView;
@end
```

CollectionCell.m

```
@implementation CollectionCell
@synthesize parseImageView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        parseImageView.frame = self.frame;
        [self addSubview:parseImageView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues. If you're not loading your cell from a nib or storyboard, and the `parseImageView` property is not an IBOutlet, the cell should have a strong reference to the imageView, so change `weak` to `strong`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *parseImageView;
```

Second, you should add the imageView to the cell's `contentView`, not the actual cell:

`[self.contentView addSubview:parseImageView];`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the weak reference. I then added self.contentView to the message but no images are showing still. Should there be a separate instance variable and set it equal to the property and add that to subview instead of adding the property to subview?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` does, but it seems that you are changing the UI in a background thread.
If `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` is really necessary, then change the code inside it to:

```
if (!error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.parseImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    });
}
```

PS. don't run `[self.ImageCollView registerClass:[CollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];` for every cell requested. Put it in viewDidLoad